Getting error in multer image upload (nodejs)
I am not getting value in the image.buffer
While debugging ,i got the following values in the imageObject
Image object: {
  fieldname: 'image',
  originalname: 'technoduce.png',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'image/png',
  destination: 'D:\\My Project\\Pjt EmployeeTrackingSystem\\ets_nodejs\\uploads',
  filename: '1715079481440_technoduce.png',
  path: 'D:\\My Project\\Pjt EmployeeTrackingSystem\\ets_nodejs\\uploads\\1715079481440_technoduce.png',
  size: 1880080
}

My requirement:
I need to save the image in the project folder and return the image url in the response. While creating User, i need to pass the image url in the request body.
So I used the multer package. It works perfectly for saving images to the local folder. However, during the writeFileSync step, I am not receiving the image.buffer value. So I cannot go after that. Please assist me to solve this issue. Thanks in Advance.
service.js
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const uploadImage = async (image) => {
    try
    {
        console.log("Image object:", image);

        const filename = Date.now() + '_' + image.originalname;
        const imagePath = path.join(__dirname, './uploads', filename); //path where the image will be saved
        console.log("ImagePath", imagePath);
        console.log("Buffer", image.buffer);
        //const data = Buffer.from(image.buffer)
        fs.writeFileSync(imagePath, image.buffer); // Write the image data to the file system
        return `/uploads/${filename}`; 
    }
    catch (error)
    {
        console.error("Error uploading image:", error);
        throw new Error('Failed to upload image');
    }
};

module.exports = {
    uploadImage
};

app.js
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, path.join(__dirname, 'uploads')); // Save uploaded images to the 'uploads' directory
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, Date.now() + '_' + file.originalname); // Rename the uploaded file with a unique name
  }
});

const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

// Serve uploaded images statically
app.use('/uploads', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'uploads')));
app.post('/uploadImage', upload.single('image'), async (req, res) => {
  try {
      if (!req.file) {
      return res.status(400).json({ message: 'No image uploaded' });
    }
    // Upload the image and get the URL
    const imageUrl = await uploadImage(req.file);
    res.status(200).json({ imageUrl });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error uploading image:", error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: 'Failed to upload image' });
  }
});


I tried using different package but its not working.

In app.js some code are missing about storage

You can use memoryStorage then the file info object will contain buffer property. It doesn't have any options.
const multer = require('multer');
const storage = multer.memoryStorage();
const upload = multer({ 
    storage: storage,
    limits:{
        fieldSize: 10485760 // 10mb
    } 
});


The value for storage seems to be not added in multer specification. You can add the value for storage like
const upload = multer({ storage: multer.memoryStorage() }).single('file')

then it will work.
